# suma con pares e impares, en java hasta cierto numero, luego haga varias operaciones

Tags: java

Tengo que hace varias operaciones.
Realizar un programa que imprima los número del 0 al 1.333, luego de esto que:

me de la Cantidad y suma de los primeros 475 números pares.
me de la Cantidad y suma de los primeros 798 números impares.
me de la Cantidad total de los números pares e impares.
me  Mostrar la suma de todos los números pares e impares.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int n = 1333, par = 0, impar = 0;
   
    System.out.printf("\n%-10s %s\n", "Pares", "Impares");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
if (i % 2 == 0) {
   
   System.out.printf("%1s %s\n","",i);
   par++;}

else {
   System.out.printf("%15s %s\n","",i);
   impar++;}
}

int suma = par + impar;

System.out.println("\nCantidad de números pares: " + par);
System.out.println("Cantidad de números impares: " + impar);
System.out.println("Suma de los pares e impares: " + suma);
  }
}
```

Comment: Por mi encantado de ayudarte, pero, ¿dónde esta el código?

Comment: Comparte el código para que la comunidad pueda revisar en más detalle el problema que estas tiniendo.

Comment: acaban de darme esto en a universidad, pero no le he entendido mucho, hasta acá he podido llegar, me han dicho que es un if donde debo editar, pero he hecho de todo, tengo desde la mañana intentando y nada... mi cabeza va a explotar

Answer (score 1):

```
int[]pares = new int[475];
int[] impares = new int[798];
int sumaPares = 0;
int sumaImpares = 0;
int indicePares = 0;
int indiceImpares = 0;

for(int i = 0; i<=1333;i++)
{
    System.out.println(i);

    if(i%2 == 0 && i <= 475)
    {
       sumaPares+=i;
       pares[indicePares] = i;
       indicePares++;
    }
    else if(i%2 == 1 && i <=798
    {
       sumaImpares += i;              
       impares[indiceImpares] = i;
       indiceImpares++;
    }
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es un ciclo que itere desde 0 hasta 1333, a medida que el ciclo se va recorriendo se va imprimiendo i, luego se pregunta si i es par mediante el módulo de su división i%2,
si es 0 es par y si es 1 es impar; el módulo de un número con dos siempre va a dar 0 o 1, también se pregunta para los pares que i sea menor que 478 que es el intervalo que te interesa, si se cumplen estas condiciones entonces se va guardando la suma de los números pares en la variable sumaPares y se guarda i en el arreglo pares mediante la variable indicePares que dice en que posición debe guardarse i en el arreglo, para los impares la explicación es bien parecida a lo q te he dicho hasta ahora.

Para saber la suma total de pares e impares después que se termine el ciclo pon esto

```
int Total = sumaPares + sumaImpares;
```

Si posteriormente deseas imprimir el arreglo de pares o impares pues lo harías con otro ciclo for ej

```
for(int i=0;i<475;i++)
{
   System.out.println(pares[i]);
}
```

Lo mismo harías con los impares.

Analiza este código y adáptalo al tuyo

Comment: he montado tu codigo, y te agradezco tu ayuda, lo necesito adicionar es que a parte de eso que tengo me de Cantidad y suma de los primeros 475 números pares. y me de  Cantidad y suma de los primeros 798 números impares.

Comment: Socio el código que te puse suma los primeros 475 pares y los primeros 798 impares y además te guarda los pares en un arreglo y los impares en otro arreglo,  no entiendo tu duda

Comment: Pero además si tu ejercicio te pide la cantidad de los primeros 475 pares pues la cantidad es precisamente 475 lo mismo pasa para los impares

Comment: yo no se como adecuar lo que me envias, no se nada de java,no se donde colocarlos, si al inicio, si es al final si es depormedio...perdona completamente mi ignorancia.